# Authentication issue using Restangular and Passport

Tags: angularjs, express, coffeescript, restangular, passport.js

I am currently working on a pet project that uses AngularJS on the frontend and Express on the 
backend. The Angular frontend talks to the backend using RESTful requests using the Restangular module. On the backend, the session is authenticated using Passport. On the browser, the authentication works fantastically well (using Postman for example, I am able to POST my login information and then GET whatever I want from the server).

The issue is that using Restangular, I first 'login' by sending a POST request with the login information. The main logic is shown below:

```
    account = Restangular.all 'login'

    $scope.loginInformation = 
        {
            username: ''
            password: ''    
        }
    succesfulLogin = (res) ->
        console.log res
    unsuccesfulLogin = () ->
        console.log "Login failed"
        console.log $scope.loginInformation
    $scope.login = () ->
        account.post($scope.loginInformation).then succesfulLogin, unsuccesfulLogin
```

Upon entering the correct username and password, the console prints the response "Login Succesful. You are now logged in" which is the response we have coded to be sent on a correct login (same response we see on postman).

Now the issue, no matter what I try to GET, every GET request done in code returns a 403 Forbidden response.

I get the same response on the console

```
GET http://[ADDRESS] 403 (Forbidden) 
Object {data: "Error: Not Authenticated", status: 403, headers: function, config: Object}
```

I don't understand how the browser works and Postman works, but my application does not.

Has anybody had any luck with a similar setup?

My intuition tells me that this has to do with the way angular is handling the cookies (not sure though).

Comment: Can you put up some sample code in a gist? `403` is supposed to be an issue with authorization, not authentication - you are logged in, but you don't have access rights - but it depends on what was implemented; not everything follows that standard.

Comment: Well, another thing I figured out about this problem was that moving my application to be on the same domain as the Restful server solved the problem. In the past, we had created CORS middleware to handle the cross domain issue. I don't know why putting it in the same domain would make it work.

Comment: That is strange. Is it possible that Restangular is doing something strange, and thus turning browser domain issues into a `403`? Would be interesting to see the Firebug network requests...

Comment: I'll look into that probably tomorrow and post a follow up.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic auth with passport and express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378937/basic-auth-with-passport-and-express)