# Basic auth with passport and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I must have missed something, but according to all the tutorials I've found, this is how you do basic auth with a node application using `express` and `passport` + `passport-local`. I know it's not according to best practice, I'm just trying to get a POC going:

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

var app = express();

var users = { 'user': 'secretpass'};

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log('Username:', username, 'password:', password);
        if (!users[username] || users[username] != password) {
            console.log('Username:', username, 'password:', password);
            return done (null, false);
        }
        return done(null, {username: username});
    }
    ));

app.use(passport.initialize());


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send ('GET request to root');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send ('POST request to root');
});

app.get('/unauthorized', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('GET Forbidden');
});

app.post('/unauthorized', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('Post Forbidden');
});

app.post('/webhook', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/unauthorized'}),
    function (req, res) {
        res.send ('authenticated!');
    }
);

var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log('Server listening at', server.address().address, 'on port', server.address().port);
});
```

What's weird is, I'm not even getting those console.log() statements in the `LocalStrategy` constructor to show me anything, so I'm guessing I really just missed something. I tried sending POST requests using both DHC and Postman,

- setting basic auth fields to username and password,
- using the format username:password@url method,
- sending username and password as form data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Basic Authentication, you need [`passport-http`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http), not `passport-local` (which is meant for authentication through form data).

Try this:

```
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
...
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(...));
...
app.post('/webhook', 
  passport.authenticate('basic', {
    session         : false,
    successRedirect : '/',
    failureRedirect : '/unauthorized'
  }), function (req, res) {
    // FWIW, this isn't useful because it's never reached, because Passport
    // will always issue a redirect (either to / or to /unauthorized)
    res.send ('authenticated!');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use passport-http module for basic auth

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
   function (username, password, done) {
      //perform auth here for user.
      //use done(null,false) if auth fails

      done(null, {
         user: "xyz"
      });


   }
));

app.get('/app', passport.authenticate('basic', {
   session: false
}), (req, res) => {
   console.log("Hello");

   res.send('ok');
});

app.listen(4000, (err, res) => {
   console.log(err, res);
   console.log('server is launched');
})
```